# is_null not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays

I am sending my js array to php. It is working fine if array has some elements. Now, my array be null. So, I am doing a checking of whether my array is null using `is_null` and it is not working as shown below:

```
  //sending array
  xmlhttp.send('myArray='+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(myArray)));
  console.log(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(myArray)));
  //shows -> %5Bnull%5D 
  console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray));
  //shows -> [null]
```

My PHP is:

```
   <?php
      if(is_null(json_decode($_POST['myArray']))){

           $arr = array("workdetails" => array(array("company_name" => "My Old Company", "role" => "web application developer", "employees" => "91")));
          echo json_encode($arr);
    }
    else {

         $data = json_decode($_POST['myArray']);
         //echo json_encode($data); // If I do this, then I am getting back [null] in js

        $arr = array("workdetails" => array(array("company_name" => "My New Company", "role" => "senior web application developer", "employees" => "911")));
        echo json_encode($arr);

    }
 ?>
```

Always else statement is getting executed even if array is `[null]`.

Comment: Check in PHP (eg via `var_dump($_POST['myArray'])`) what it is there. Probably `empty()` instead will solve this

Comment: I checked with empty and isset but nothing working. See my post I have written there.

Comment: see if anything is being posted, try var_dump($_POST);

Comment: `$_POST['myArray']` being null and containing null is two totally different things. `null` is null, `[null]` is not -- it's an array containing a null.

Comment: `[null]` and `null` are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

From manual:

> NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

So probably you have simply valid data.

If you put

```
$_POST['myArray'] = 'arweiouwreauiwaeruirewaiu';
```

just before if it will go to `is_null` condition because it's invalid Json data

Even if  `$_POST['myArray'] == ''` or `$_POST['myArray'] == null`  or `$_POST['myArray']` is not set you go to `is_null` condition so probably `$_POST['myArray']` is not null as you expect.